# WooCommerce Print Invoice & Packing Lists - Change Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a WooCommerce store set up with products in several categories and using the Print Invoice & Packing List plugin to generate packing lists for orders.

The plugin orders products by default based on the first category they are listed in, in alphabetical order.

I'm trying to set the plugin to ignore a preset list of categories by ID, so all products will still display, but only listed under the category I've allowed instead of the first category in alphabetical order.

I've read through the [Invoice & Packing List dev reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-print-invoices-packing-lists-developer-reference/) grabbed a [SkyVerge snippet](https://github.com/skyverge/wc-plugins-snippets/tree/master/woocommerce-print-invoices-packing-lists) and created a custom plugin which will disable categories completely, but can't for the life of me figure out how the WooCommerce hooks should work to ignore certain categories.

This is what I have in the custom plguin at the moment, which simply removes the categories from packing lists:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) 

add_filter( 'wc_pip_packing_list_group_items_by_category', '__return_false' );

function sv_wc_pip_packing_list_grouping( $group_items, $order_id, $document_type ) {
 if ( 'pick-list' !== $document_type ) {
  return $group_items;
 }
 $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
 if ( ! $order->is_paid() ) {
  return false;
 }
 return $group_items;
}
add_filter( 'wc_pip_packing_list_group_items_by_category', 'sv_wc_pip_packing_list_grouping', 10, 3 );
```

Appreciate any help to identify how to define item categories in this function.

Answer (score 0):

i think you could try this, section Document Filters from your documentation link:

wc_pip_packing_list_exclude_item

Params: $exclude, $product, $item, $item_data
Return: (bool)
Filters if an order item should be excluded from the packing list.

in your filter function, you should be able to test the category from `$product`, or at least get relevant info to query it. Then you just return `true` or `false` following the case

Comment: Thanks Kaddath, I wasn't clear enough in my question so have edited it. That would exclude an item entirely, but I'm wanting the item to still be visible, just under one of the categories I haven't ignored.

Comment: ok, i'll have a look when i have a bit of time, i have not found the filter you are using in the documentation link, is $group_items the complete ordered list of the items shown?

Comment: As far as I know the $group_items should be returning the list of items, yes. In the snippet I've got it's simply ordering them by order id which I understand, and that snippet is from the SkyVerge modules on GitHub and was the closest I could get.

Comment: ok, because if this is the variable that contains the ordered list and that is used to diplay them on the page, you could just add custom code inside the function that re-arranges the items before you return it. have you tried to modify i and see if the page changes?